# Variable in the useState not updating in useEffect callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, use-effect

```
const Tweet = ({ tweet, checkedList, setCheckedList }) => {
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    checkedList === [] && setChecked(false);
  }, [checkedList, isChecked]);
  return (
    <div className="tweet">
      <h3>Name : {tweet.name} </h3>
      <p>{tweet.tweet}</p>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={isChecked}
        onChange={() => {
          setChecked(!isChecked);
          checkedList.find((e) => e === tweet.id) === undefined
            ? setCheckedList([...checkedList, tweet.id])
            : setCheckedList(checkedList.filter((e) => e !== tweet.id));
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have a tweet component that has its own state. There is an external checkedList with is basically an array of checked tweet ids.
But once I reset the `checkedList = []` , I am trying to reset the checked tweets by useEffect. But can't do it.
I want all tweets state to be unchecked. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `checkedList === []` will never be true because `[]` is a new array that is different to the array stored in `checedList`. If you want to check an empty array, you can check the length `checkedList.length`

Comment: This fixed doesnt work. Also I am trying to toggle the state externally with a diff button , but it isn't changing.

Comment: What is your updated check doing instead (what does your updated code look like)?

Comment: The state which is bind to checkbox is not being edited externally. I tried a new state, which works fine, but once I connect to checkbox , it doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: Did you change your check to use length instead? What does that check look like in your code now? See if you can update your question to include a reproducible example of your issue using something like a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/5648954) or code sandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-worker-cve8qy?file=/src/App.js:954-2084

Comment: Seems to work if you use `checked={isChecked}` instead of `defaultChecked={isChecked}` like you've done in your question

Comment: Noep. Doesn't work

Comment: What isn't working (here is a version that I think is working: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-star-evy1xv). If I select the checkboxes and click the "Move to memes" button, it clears the checkboxes. Isn't that what you're after? Or is there some other way to reproduce the issue you're having

Comment: Hey , checked it . Its working.  Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 0):

`checkedList === []`  is will never be true .

try to check the length of the   checkedList array .